# MVC4 NULL Reference Exception was unhandle by user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(AdulLiteracyTeachers adulliteracyteachers, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.AdulLiteracyTeachers.Add(adulliteracyteachers);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.DistID = new SelectList(db.Districts, "DistID", "DistName", adulliteracyteachers.DistID);
            return View(adulliteracyteachers);
        }
```

here is my view :

```
<p>
<label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple"/>

    <input name="Upload" type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

On create button I got this error in MVC 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Which Object? Did you put enctype="multipart/form-data" as the form attribute?

Comment: Probably need to add more details to this. Where does it break? What line? It should be pretty easy to determine which object is null.

Comment: at which line it gives error?

Comment: Thank you All I was wondering but I have fixed it :D :D :D :D D